# What is known about the solutions to $\varphi(a)+\varphi(b)=\varphi(a+b)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

As of late I have been researching Euler's Totient function.  For the last week or so I have specifically been studying the equation:  $\varphi(a)+\varphi(b)=\varphi(a+b)$

While the equation isn't true for all $a$ and $b$ I believe I've found the criteria that need to be met for the equation to be true.

I have tried to find information regarding the equation but haven't had much luck.  I would like to know what research has been done previously on this equation to see if my results are, by any chance, new.

Thanks for the help!

Here is my theorem:

For $a≠b$, $φ(a)+φ(b)=φ(a+b)$ when $a=2^m p_1 p_2…p_k$ and $b=2^n p_1 p_2…p_k p_{k+1}$.
In addition to the extra requirements that $m$ and $n$ be $≥0$ but both may not be $0$, (in other words, either $a$ or $b$ may be odd but they cannot both be odd) and $2^{m-n}+p_{k+1}$ must be prime.

In addition I have used a slightly different representation for $a$ and $b$ than the standard canonical representation, but the $p$ terms do not all have to be distinct.

Ex: $a=2^3(3)(3)$ and $b=2^2(3)(3)(11)$

The equation is also true if $a=b$ and $a,b$ are even.

Comment: My first thought is that finding a useful necessary and sufficent criterion might be very difficult, since knowing the factorizations of $a$ and $b$ does not help at all with factoring $a+b$.

Comment: @FofX I don't expect that there is much research out there on your question because of the reason spin gave. Could you explain your criteria and give us something more to work with?

Comment: Sure I can try but this LaTeX thing is new to me.